# Find values of user meta table when its grouped by relation filed in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I want to filter records by exam_score and type Eg: find users where the exam is CAT and score between 50 to 100. please check these images. The exams are grouped by relation field value.
[image: Laravel Code]
[image: Sql Table]

Comment: If anyone wants to assist and test the code or suggest working code, then can't do that from an image.  Please post all code and data samples as *text*.  Data samples should be posted in table format or for MySQL as CREATE TABLE / INSERT statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT 
    um1.`user_id`, 
    um1.`value` AS exam_type, 
    um2.`value` AS score 
FROM user_meta AS um1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        `user_id`, `value`, `group` 
    FROM user_meta 
    WHERE `key` = 'score'
) AS um2 ON um1.`user_id` = um2.`user_id` 
         AND um1.`group` = um2.`group`
WHERE um1.`key` = 'exam_type' 
    AND um1.`value` = 'CAT' 
    AND um1.`group` = 'exam'
    AND CONVERT(um2.`value`, UNSIGNED INTEGER) BETWEEN 50 AND 100
```

With the filter exam took:

```sql
SELECT 
    um1.`user_id`, 
    um1.`value` AS exam_type, 
    um2.`value` AS score,
    um3.`value` AS took_exam
FROM user_meta AS um1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        `user_id`, `value`, `group` 
    FROM user_meta 
    WHERE `key` = 'score'
) AS um2 ON um1.`user_id` = um2.`user_id` 
         AND um1.`group` = um2.`group`
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        `user_id`, `value`, `group` 
    FROM user_meta 
    WHERE `key` = 'took_exam'
) AS um3 ON um1.`user_id` = um3.`user_id` 
         AND um1.`group` = um3.`group`
WHERE um1.`key` = 'exam_type' 
    AND um1.`value` = 'CAT' 
    AND um1.`group` = 'exam'
    AND CONVERT(um2.`value`, UNSIGNED INTEGER) BETWEEN 50 AND 100
```

**Another approach (Not preferable):**

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        user_id,
        MAX(CASE WHEN `key` = 'exam_type' THEN `value` ELSE '' END) exam_type,
        MAX(CASE WHEN `key` = 'score' THEN CONVERT(`value` , UNSIGNED INTEGER) ELSE 0 END) score,
        MAX(CASE WHEN `key` = 'took_exam' THEN `value` ELSE '' END) took_exam
    FROM user_meta
    WHERE (`key` = 'exam_type' AND `value` = 'CAT') 
        OR (`key` = 'took_exam' AND `value` IN ('yes', 'no'))
        OR (`key` = 'score')
    GROUP BY user_id
) a WHERE score BETWEEN 50 AND 100
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but its giving an error: Error in query (1248): Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: @CoursesCart Try now, Edited the query

Comment: Thanks so much it is working now, but what about If I want to filter with "took_exam" with yes/no?

Comment: @CoursesCart Edited query with another approach as well